# Caliburn Micro and Castle Windsor Bootstrapper - Register View Model classes in bootstrapper

Tags: wpf, castle-windsor, viewmodel, caliburn.micro, bootstrapping

I use Castle Windsor bootstrapper in my WPF app. I tried register view model classes to windsor container.

I have all view models classes in namespace sample.viewmodels

So I tried this:

```
        _windsorContainer.Register(AllTypes.FromAssembly(GetType().Assembly)
                                       .Where(x => x.Namespace.EndsWith("ViewModels"))
                                       .Configure(x => x.LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Singleton)));
```

Or this way for register view model classes to container:

```
    _windsorContainer.Register(AllTypes.FromAssembly(GetType().Assembly)
                                   .Where(x => x.Namespace.Equals("Sample.ViewModels"))
                                   .Configure(x => x.LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Singleton)));
```

This way doesn't work.  I don’t why. `MainViewModel / ChildViewModel` property is null.

If I use this style it works good.

```
        ////Shell
        _windsorContainer.Register(
            Component.For<IShellViewModel>()
                .ImplementedBy<ShellViewModel>()
                .LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Singleton));

        //Main screen
        _windsorContainer.Register(
            Component.For<IMainViewModel>()
                .ImplementedBy<MainViewModel>()
                .LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Singleton));

        //Child screen
        _windsorContainer.Register(
            Component.For<IChildViewModel>()
                .ImplementedBy<ChildViewModel>()
                .LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Singleton));
```

What is bad in first case?

Here I have view models:

```
namespace Sample.ViewModels
{
    public interface IShellViewModel
    {}

    public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.AllActive,
        IShellViewModel
    {
        public IMainViewModel MainViewModel { get; set; }

        public IChildViewModel ChildViewModel { get; set; }

        protected override void OnInitialize()
        {
            DisplayName = "Castle Windsor Boostraper";
            base.OnInitialize();
        }
    }

    public interface IMainViewModel : IScreen
    {
        void SayHello();
    }

    public class MainViewModel : Screen, IMainViewModel
    {
        public void SayHello()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello from MainViewModel");
        }
    }
    public interface IChildViewModel : IScreen
    {
        void SayHello();
    }

    public class ChildViewModel : Screen, IChildViewModel
    {
        public void SayHello()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello from ChildViewModel");
        }
    }
}
```

**EDITED:**

I little update registration part:

```
        _windsorContainer.Register(AllTypes.FromAssembly(GetType().Assembly)
                                       .Pick()
                                       .WithService.DefaultInterface()
                                       .Configure(x => x.LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Singleton)));
```

It work but I am not sure if this is best way.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to do something like this to register your viewmodels in Castle Windosr

```
_windsorContainer.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly()
    .Where(x => x.Namespace.EndsWith("ViewModels"))
    .WithService.AllInterfaces()
    .WithService.Self()
    .If(s => !s.IsAbstract)
    .Configure(x => x.LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Singleton)));
```

But I'm wondering why you register your viewmodels as singleton? I would register them as transient, so you could instanciate multiple different viewmodels for the same view in the application. I also use a marker-interface for my viewmodels, so I don't have to rely on the viewmodels on being in a namespace that ends with "ViewModels".

```
_windsorContainer.Register(Classes
    .FromThisAssembly()
    .BasedOn<IViewModelBase>()
    .WithServiceAllInterfaces()
    .WithServiceSelf()
    .LifestyleTransient()
```

Answer (score 1):

in the first example you are only registering the concrete types to be singletons, the second example you associate the relevant interfaces with the implementations. since your properties expose the models as interfaces, the first code part will not be able to satisfy those properties.

Comment: Thanl you. I little edited my registration part of code but I am not sure if this is best way.